# Using an ActiveX Command Button to Put Data into Different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code to collect numbers from a column then put those numbers within a specific range into another column on a different worksheet. The problem is that the ActiveX Command button that I'm using is private to the first worksheet. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer

X = Range(J2).Value
Y = Range(K2).Value

RuntimeLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

If CommandButton1 = True Then

    For I = 2 To RuntimeLR

        If I >= X And I <= Y Then
        
            Worksheets("Calculate Runtime").Cells(p + 1, 1) = I
            
            p = p + 1
            
        End If
            
    Next I
        
End If
            

End Sub
```

Is there a way to make the ActiveX Control Button public? Thank you.

Comment: Change `Private` to `Public`? Though I imagine this is an XY problem. What is your end goal?

Comment: Why is it an XY problem? My end goal is to transfer the numbers within the range into a column on another worksheet.

Comment: Does changing `Private` to `Public` answer your question?

Comment: What do you expect form the code line `If CommandButton1 = True Then`? Then do you want calling `CommandButton1_Click` event from other worksheets, too?

Comment: I've already tried changing it to Public and it didn't work. But why would it be an XY problem?

Comment: `Private` and `Public` have nothing to do with your issues. You need your ranges to be in quotes `Range("J2").Value` And you need to get rid of the `If` statement because that won't ever be true, if the button is pressed then the sub runs, that is the entire purpose of an event sub.

Comment: ^^^^^ That's why it's an XY problem.

Comment: The code for that line results when the button is pressed, right?

Comment: `p` is not declared btw and should be.

Comment: You're getting compile errors which only highlight the sub because it hasn't gone line by line yet it's failing to compile not execute.

Comment: So I should just write the button and get rid of the if statement? Will that fix it?

Comment: If you try clarifying one of my question, please tag me (@FaneDuru)... If you address to me, no, that code line does not do anything... The button runs its code when it is pressed. There is not any Boolean variable associated to its Click event, You should declare all used variables. (`p` inclusive). Then `X = Range(J2).Value` has no meaning, if `J2` is not a variable. It, probably, should be "J2"...

Comment: @FaneDuru So I don't even declare it? Just write the code?

Comment: Where did you declare `p` variable? Do you know what a declaration means? Did you declare a variable `J2` and I cannot see it? Even being so, not giving to it any value, the code line in discussion does not give any value to `X`.

Comment: @FaneDuru I just added the declaration. I got rid of the If statement and it puts numbers within the new worksheet but not from the first worksheet. It just lists numbers between the range declared.

Comment: Please, put `Option Explicit` on top of the module and you will be obliged to declare all involved variables, so you will be also warn when some strange use of some words, like the code line I mentioned before, will appear in your code...

Comment: The "range declared" is something not existing. You did not declare any range. And the use of a range to obtain `X` and `Y` is wrong, as we tried explaining to you...

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, thanks for your help with this. I changed the code based on your suggestions, but the data being transferred aren't the individual numbers in the first worksheet but just numbers between the range. What would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: You received an answer. It is at least polite to send some feedback to the user who tried helping you. It practically corrected all your problems. If it does not do what you want, you should better explain **in words** what you want accomplishing. We could only deduce looking to your existing pseudo code...

Answer (score 0):

`Private` and `Public` only dictate where the code can be called from. In this case since it is an activeX command button event sub it exists on a worksheet's code behind. Only that button or subs in the same worksheet code behind can call it. So that isn't the issue.

There are three issues with the code here:

1. You need to declare all variables, or remove `option explicit`. `option explicit` is very handy though so don't remove it.
2. `Range` accepts strings (generally speaking), it thinks your `Range(J2)` means you have a variable called `J2` you want `Range("J2")` to point to Cell J 2.
3. Your `If` will always be false, Command Buttons don't have a boolean for you to compare to like that. A checkbox or the like would, however.

All together:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim X As Long 'I made these longs, integer is worthless in VBA don't use it ever
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim runtimelr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Long
    
    X = Range("J2").Value
    Y = Range("K2").Value

    runtimelr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To runtimelr

        If i >= X And i <= Y Then
        
            Worksheets("Calculate Runtime").Cells(p + 1, 1) = i
            
            p = p + 1
            
        End If
            
    Next i
End Sub
```

As an aside, your loop is not calculating run-time. It takes far less than 1 second for it to perform an iteration.

What you're looking for:

```
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim runtimelr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Long
    
    X = Range("J2").Value
    Y = Range("K2").Value
    
    runtimelr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To runtimelr

        If Me.Cells(i, 4).Value >= X And Me.Cells(i, 4).Value <= Y Then
        
            Worksheets("Calculate Runtime").Cells(p + 1, 1) = Me.Cells(i, 4).Value
            
            p = p + 1
            
        End If
            
    Next i
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I guess I should've been clearer when I wrote this post. I'm just trying to move numbers in a column between a range to another column. I'm not trying to calculate anything. Doesn't the code written above do that? Why am I just getting numbers between the range and not the numbers specified in the first column?

Comment: The loop above goes from 2 to however many rows you have on the command button sheet assuming `Range(J2)` is less than or equal to `I` and `Range(K2)` is greater than or equal to `I`. It then pastes the value of `I` into `column(1)` of Calculate Runtime.

Comment: @user58518 Do you want pasting the value from column D:D, if the condition is `True`, or the number of the row where the condition is `True`, as your code looks to do? For the first case, you should use `Worksheets("Calculate Runtime").Cells(p + 1, 1) .value = Cells(i, 4).value`

Comment: Yes I want to past the value of D:D into the new column not the value of I.

Comment: @user58518 do you want the `If` to mean the value in Column D is between J2 and K2 or the row number is between J2 and K2?

Comment: The value in Column D is between J2 and K2. I changed some of the code. It seemed to work but a few of the values are still not within the range.
`If Cells(I, 4) >= X And Cells(I, 4) <= Y Then`
`Worksheets("Calculate Runtime").Cells(p + 1, 1) = Cells(I, 4)`

Comment: So I'm basically getting the value within the cell instead of the number of the cell.

Comment: Don't know why there are still some numbers outside of the range though.

Comment: If `J2 = 2` and `K2 = 10` only numbers 2-10 would be pasted. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @Warcupine It seems to work but there are a couple numbers that are outside of the range. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @warcupine Mostly towards the end.

Comment: @warcupine It seems that it's working until it gets to a certain point towards the end of the column.

Comment: I have no idea what your data looks like so I'm unsure I can help with that. Presumably the value in the cells isn't inclusively between the values in J2 and K2

Comment: @warcupine I figured out what was wrong. The sheet still had values from the last time I calculated it. So the last few values still were above the range. Thanks for your help.